# ExpandableListView In a DialogFragment crash

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working on a ExpandableListView in a DialogFragment to Add as Filters. It should look like this [Filter Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoxZA.png).

Now to implement this I have done something like this.

```
public class FilterDialogForCharity extends DialogFragment {
MyExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView listView;
ArrayList<String> titles;
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> group;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    titles = new ArrayList<>();
    group = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    initialiseList();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_dialog,container,false);
    listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_filter_list);
    expandableListAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(titles,getActivity(),group);
    listView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    return view;
}


private void initialiseList() {

    titles.add("Work");
    titles.add("Region");
    titles.add("Rating");
    // Adding child data
    ArrayList<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    ArrayList<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    ArrayList<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    group.put(titles.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    group.put(titles.get(1), nowShowing);
    group.put(titles.get(2), comingSoon);

    expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}
}

MyExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class FilterDialogForCharity extends DialogFragment {
MyExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView listView;
ArrayList<String> titles;
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> group;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    titles = new ArrayList<>();
    group = new HashMap<>();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_dialog,container,false);
    listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_filter_list);
    expandableListAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(titles,getActivity(),group);
    initialiseList();
    listView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    return view;
}

private void initialiseList() {

    titles.add("Work");
    titles.add("Region");
    titles.add("Rating");
    // Adding child data
    ArrayList<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    ArrayList<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    ArrayList<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    group.put(titles.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    group.put(titles.get(1), nowShowing);
    group.put(titles.get(2), comingSoon);

   expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}
StackTrace Log

```
    03-25 02:19:28.609 17728-17728/healthandcharity.socialcause.care E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
03-25 02:19:28.609 17728-17728/healthandcharity.socialcause.care E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@c29c17d
03-25 02:19:28.649 17728-17728/healthandcharity.socialcause.care E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at healthandcharity.socialcause.care.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:73)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2934)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3094)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2643)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1573)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1890)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1486)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7467)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
03-25 02:19:28.869 17728-17728/healthandcharity.socialcause.care E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: healthandcharity.socialcause.care, PID: 17728
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at healthandcharity.socialcause.care.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:73)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2934)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3094)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20182)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2643)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1573)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1890)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1486)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7467)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: post stacktrace where it crashes.

Comment: Sorry. My bad.I have posted the stacktrace now.